# Concatenating Text in a Chart Series Name Box

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to alter a chart legend / series name to concatenate some additional text to the series label from the original data set.  Following the instructions found [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Modify-chart-legend-entries-d822dd57-af28-4c3e-93d1-d320e6239843), I get to the **Select Data Source** dialog, where I select the legend entry I want to change from the **Legend Entries (Series)** box, and then click **Edit**.  That brings up this dialog:

[image: Edit Series Dialog 1]

What I want to do is concatenate some words to the original series label coming from that `DATA!$C$3` field, like so:

[image]

However, when I do that, I get the familiar "The formula you typed contains an error" dialog.  This to me is strange, because what I have there is a legal formula.  It's almost as if only a subset of the formula syntax is supported in this dialog.

Is there a correct syntax or workaround for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartSeriesFormula.html) credits "The series formula is an Excel formula like any other." it does seem a little quirky to me. He also mentions:

> The Series Name can be blank, a text string in double quotation marks, a reference to a worksheet range (one or more cells), or a reference to a named range (named formula).

For simplicity, if viable you might consider going to Data!C3 and changing whatever is there (eg `x`) to:

```
="x"&"(Rt. Axis)"
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I was trying to avoid that approach but I think you're right, it might be the only way.

Comment: These RefEdit-style boxes can only contain a link to a range, whether a cell address or defined name, or static data in the form of an array (for x or y values) or a single value (for series name).

Comment: @pnuts - "Quirky" makes the SERIES formula different from other Excel formulas?